# DVD not accessible/readable on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: video, dvd

When inserting a video DVD in my Laptop with Ubuntu 15.10, it is not mounted like usually when I insert a data DVD or also another video DVD :(

So I think maybe it is somehow protected? It is possible to view the DVD with a standalone DVD player, but opening it with Ubuntu 15.10, Windows 7, Windows 8 and Suse doesn't work :( I tried it on laptop and several PCs...

Inserting the related video DVD to a Windows PC just don't automount anything and the DVD device is seen as empty...

On Ubuntu 15.10 (my main system) I installed also all the relevant things I have found in several forums (libdvdcss2 libdvdread4 libdvdcss-dev, ...) and tried it with several players, but nothing works. I think, the first problem is that /dev/sr0 can not be mounted.

Ejecting the DVD with `eject /dev/sr0` or `eject /cdrom` works.
I have additionally used regionset to set the region.

`sudo lshw -C disk` gives following output:

```
**-cdrom
       Beschreibung: DVD-RAM writer
       Produkt: DVDRAM GUA0N
       Hersteller: HL-DT-ST
       Physische ID: 0.0.0
       Bus-Informationen: scsi@1:0.0.0
       Logischer Name: /dev/cdrom
       Logischer Name: /dev/cdrw
       Logischer Name: /dev/dvd
       Logischer Name: /dev/dvdrw
       Logischer Name: /dev/sr0
       Version: AL00
       Fähigkeiten: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
       Konfiguration: ansiversion=5 status=ready
     *-medium
          Physische ID: 0
          Logischer Name: /dev/cdrom*
```

`ls -al /dev/cdrom*` gives following output:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3 Feb 21 12:43 /dev/cdrom -> sr0
```

`lsblk` gives following output:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 111,8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   200M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0    71G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0  40,6G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1   3,7G  0 rom
```

`sudo mount -t auto /dev/cdrom /media/xxx/555` gives following output:

```
mount: /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

So what is here the real problem? I have a video DVD which can be played on a standalone DVD player but PCs can't play the stuff!
VLC player gives the following message:

`vlc-wrapper /dev/sr0`

```
[00007fa2e4000e28] filesystem access error: read error: Input/output error
libdvdread:DVDOpenFileUDF:UDFFindFile /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.IFO failed
libdvdread:DVDOpenFileUDF:UDFFindFile /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.BUP failed
libdvdread: Can't open file VIDEO_TS.BUP.
[00007fa2ec005c78] core input error: open of `dvdsimple:///dev/sr0' failed
```

Does anyone else maybe have such problem(s) and does anyone know what to do in such case to copy the content of this kind of video DVD to a PC (so I can watch it on my TV (from USB stick) or tablet or other portable devices...)?

Comment: I hardly use DVDs anymore, but I tried two of my movie disks in VLC, first in Ubuntu 15.10, then in Windows 10. They didn't play, and the first one popped a message in VLC (in Windows) that the content was copyright protected. However they played perfectly in PowerDVD 10, trial version, again Windows. I remember I used software from dvdvideosoft.com, in Windows, to rip my DVD movies, and it worked. I'm not familiar with any Linux software for this purpose.

Comment: Edit - turns out this DVD ripper is no longer available. There is another Windows app called DVD Decrypter, but Linux alternatives are listed here - http://alternativeto.net/software/free-dvd-decrypter/?platform=linux Haven't tried any of them myself.